Angular Library CSS not working in main project after upgrading from v15 to v18
I have an angular library and angular project both were on v15 with material on 14, Now i have upgraded all to v18.
In the library, there are many components. Each having their own scss files. When running the library tester the CSS works fine.
But when i package the library and install it in the main project, All of the custom css has stopped working. Even the inline styles are not being applied.

Is Material still on v14?

@JSONDerulo Material is now at 18

@AchalUtkarsh The HTML structure must have changed, so your custom CSS is breaking, you need to rework the CSS to work for angular 18 I guess

For trial, i added a div and added a css class with background red. This worked fine in tester but didn't in main project @NarenMurali

It's on line 38 of material-overrides.scss. It uses @use 'internals/material/core' which doesn't exist anymore and... Just kidding. How are we supposed to debug this with no code? With no indication of the testing that you were supposed to have done as you upgraded Angular and Angular Material from v15 to v16, and from v16 to v17, and from v17 to v18?
